# How to Integrate PHPList with the Existing Site

Tags: php, integrate, phplist

The existing site has it own "users" table in a database. I'm wondering how to integrate PHPList with the existing site so that a user can check the newsletter during registration. I installed phplist thru cpanel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution till '08?

Answer (score 2):

PHPList lets you define a table prefix to avoid name clashes

See "Using a database prefix" : http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigDatabase

Comment: Probably why it wasn't accepted. So a gaping opportunity for you to claim the prize!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is keeping both tables in sync manually, both by a daily run script and on demand when a user account is modified in the main site. I don't propagate changes from phplist to the master app tough.